# how can i fix the password to read in mysql

Tags: mysql, bash, terminal, quotes, mysql-connector

I have a problem .I have the code that needs to connect to a MySQL database in the TERMINAL.
but i can not open because this password does not support **%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY**

```
mysql -N -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u test -p%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY -D read
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all.I found the problem by this way

```
username='test'
password='%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY'
database='read'
mysql -N -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u $username -p$password -D $database
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Put mysql -h localhost -u username -p
It will ask for password in terminal

Comment: i created the script but i do not want ask it in the terminal. how can i set password for supporting without issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can put single quotes around the password

```
mysql -N -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u test -p'%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY' -D read
```

Comment: it does not work .the issue is 'mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user' but already i am suing in mysql workbench.!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `$` character is interpreted specially by the shell. See following illustration

```
$ echo %pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY
%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8}uY
$ echo '%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY'
%pK]-K8FgAM,HS8$7}uY
```

So, please enclose the password in single quote.

Comment: it does not work. this issue ] and } how can i solve it?